# Nodemon is losing console output when the process is crashing

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, nodemon

I am not sure if this is purely Windows issue. I don't have option to test anywhere else. Given this really simple code (Coffeescript):

```
console.log('Calling console.log')
console.error('Calling console.error')
console.log('Calling console.log second time - fails')
console.error('Calling console.error second time - fails')
nonexisting.throwError()
```

Running it directly with `coffee app.coffee` it works just fine and I get this:

```
Calling console.log
Calling console.error
Calling console.log second time - fails
Calling console.error second time - fails
ReferenceError: nonexisting is not defined
....
```

However running `nodemon app.coffee` gives me just this:

```
17 Mar 20:38:56 - [nodemon] starting `coffee.cmd server.coffee`
Calling console.log
Calling console.error
17 Mar 20:38:56 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Not only there isn't exception info at all, but also later log messages are swallowed for some reason. In more complex scenario I have no method to actually find the reason of crash. I tried to debug, but everything seems fine, console.log/error is called, but it's just not displayed for some reason. And exception is caught by Coffeescript and send directly to stderr.

I wanted to use [debug utility](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug) to have nice verbose output during development in the console and make it easier to find issues. But with this troublemaker it's not possible. Once uncaught exception occurs, I have to stop nodemon and run whole thing manually to find the error. All the elegance of the solution goes away with this :(

Anyone have idea what could be causing this and if there is some possible solution ?

Windows 7 64bit
Node 0.10.26
Nodemon 1.0.15
Coffeescript 1.7.1

Comment: Can you try running `nodemon --nodejs --debug app.coffee` and see if anything changes?

Comment: I run this coffee file with `nodemon`, `forever`, `node-supervisor`, and `node-dev`. `pm2` is not tested because I can't install it on my windows laptop. Only `node-dev` can output the desired message. Ref: [Comparison: Tools to Automate Restarting Node.js Server After Code Changes](http://strongloop.com/strongblog/comparison-tools-to-automate-restarting-node-js-server-after-code-changes-forever-nodemon-nodesupervisor-nodedev/)

Comment: @mutil No change except node debugger kicks in.

Comment: @bnuhero Thanks, I will give the node-dev a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The messages are being suppressed because the process is spawned using:

```
child_process.spawn('coffee.cmd', ['server.coffee'], { stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe']);
```

In particular the `pipe` on `stderr` is the issue, because when the child exits, the pipe is full (or appears to be from the first `console.error`) so the next message isn't put in the pipe when the child dies.

I've updated nodemon to be smarter about when it uses `pipe`, because in most cases, using `process.stdout` on `stdio` works just fine, and also means this original example script echos out the errors as you'd expect.

The [issue you filed](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/311) has also be closed in nodemon@1.0.17

I should add, the title of this SO question is misleading (it reads as if nodemon hides all console output) - it doesn't hide console output - it was losing console output when the process was crashing. None the less, it's fixed - yay!

Comment: Yeah, I suck at making good titles for questions. I have updated it with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I have an hint, but cannot prove my feeling.

When executing your program with coffee, the log messages are blocking. The error at line 5 occured while the 4 traces were already issued to console.

Whatever the monitoring tool used, the principle are nearly the same: spawn a child process that will host your app and monitor its lifecycle.
It means that your console output is redirected from the child process to the host one, that displays it.

I bet that the failure is processed prioritaryto the log messages, and thus, the host process cuts the channel before having time to display the remaining logs.

Comment: That actually makes sense, thanks. So it's more likely a bug in the tool then anything that I can do about.